# Asynchronous HttpClient calls not shown as dependency in Azure App insights for App service automatically

Tags: azure, async-await, httpclient, azure-application-insights

I am new to Azure app insights and want to know why are Asynchronous HttpClient calls not shown as dependency automatically in Azure App insights for App service.
Also, what configuration changes or code changes should I make in ASP.NET project for tracking http dependencies ?

When I refer documentation it says "A dependency is a component that is called by your application. It's typically a service called using HTTP, or a database, or a file system. Application Insights measures the duration of dependency calls, whether its failing or not, along with additional information like name of dependency and so on. You can investigate specific dependency calls, and correlate them to requests and exceptions."

Comment: A new observation:
I see the Http dependency being tracked as AppDependency for a request in logs of Application Insights telemetry but it is not tracked in Azure portal under dependency. What can be the reason for it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below example of code to track `http dependency` automatically

```cs
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TelemetryConfiguration configuration = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();

            configuration.InstrumentationKey = "removed";
            configuration.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new HttpDependenciesParsingTelemetryInitializer());

            var telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(configuration);
            using (InitializeDependencyTracking(configuration))
            {
                // run app...

                telemetryClient.TrackTrace("Hello World!");

                using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
                {
                    // Http dependency is automatically tracked!
                    httpClient.GetAsync("https://microsoft.com").Wait();
                }

            }

            // before exit, flush the remaining data
            telemetryClient.Flush();

            // flush is not blocking when not using InMemoryChannel so wait a bit. There is an active issue regarding the need for `Sleep`/`Delay`
            // which is tracked here: https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/407
            Task.Delay(5000).Wait();

        }

        static DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule InitializeDependencyTracking(TelemetryConfiguration configuration)
        {
            var module = new DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule();

            // prevent Correlation Id to be sent to certain endpoints. You may add other domains as needed.
            module.ExcludeComponentCorrelationHttpHeadersOnDomains.Add("core.windows.net");
            module.ExcludeComponentCorrelationHttpHeadersOnDomains.Add("core.chinacloudapi.cn");
            module.ExcludeComponentCorrelationHttpHeadersOnDomains.Add("core.cloudapi.de");
            module.ExcludeComponentCorrelationHttpHeadersOnDomains.Add("core.usgovcloudapi.net");
            module.ExcludeComponentCorrelationHttpHeadersOnDomains.Add("localhost");
            module.ExcludeComponentCorrelationHttpHeadersOnDomains.Add("127.0.0.1");

            // enable known dependency tracking, note that in future versions, we will extend this list. 
            // please check default settings in https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/blob/develop/WEB/Src/DependencyCollector/DependencyCollector/ApplicationInsights.config.install.xdt

            module.IncludeDiagnosticSourceActivities.Add("Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus");
            module.IncludeDiagnosticSourceActivities.Add("Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs");

            // initialize the module
            module.Initialize(configuration);

            return module;
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE**:  -

> Based on the [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/worker-service#frequently-asked-questions) **Azure Monitor Application Insights Agent currently supports ASP.NET 4.x only.**

For more information please refer the below links:

- MS DOC: [Application Insights for .NET console applications(Source code)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/console) & [Automatically dependency tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-dependencies#setup-automatic-dependency-tracking-in-console-apps)
- GitHub : [LINK1](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/issues/582) & [LINK2](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/693)